# Setting a timeout for tweepy

Tags: python, python-2.7, tweepy

I'm using tweepy for sending tweets, so far so good.
in the last 10 minutes, for some reason, twitter.com isn't working for me,
but **that's not the issue**. The issue is, that in this situation,

```
api.update_status(msg)
```

takes a loooong time(1 min approximately) before the error raised.

```
 [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed..
```

How can I set the time out for lets say 3-5 sec, so if after 5 sec twitter.com isn't working, it will raise error 10060 right away?

I tried, without success:

```
api.update_status(msg, timeout=5)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `timeout` attribute when initializing the **API**, not when using a status method:

```
api = tweepy.API(timeout=5) #default=60
```

*For some reason this option isn't listed in the official [documentation](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/api.html), but you can find it in [the actual code](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py).*

Comment: api = tweepy.API(auth,timeout=5) works for me, Thanks.